# Why is the application name not being set for my custom role provider?

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

I've implemented a custom role provider for an ASP.NET application.  I've derived my class from System.Web.Security.RoleProvider and implemented all the abstract methods and properties.  I'm configuring my provider with an applicationName in the web.config, à la:

```
 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="MvcApplication1.CustomRoleProvider" applicationName="Foo"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

However, the ApplicationName property of my provider is not being set accordingly.  Why?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to implementing the abstract methods from System.Web.Security.RoleProvider, you also need to override the `Initialize()` method.  Attributes in the provider element in web.config that aren't handled by System.Configuration.ProviderSettings, like applicationName, are passed to the custom role provider via `Initialize()`.  Adding the following to your implementation of `Initialize()` will set the ApplicationName property of the custom role provider to the value provided by the applicationName attribute in the web.config:

```
   if (config["applicationName"] != null)
       ApplicationName = config["applicationName"];
```